# Questions about Android Management API in Kiosk mode

Tags: kiosk-mode, android-management-api

This application is for tablets for students in K-12.  Thank you for any help or pointers.  The basic management software is up and running just fine.

1. Is there a way to upload wallpaper in Kiosk mode?  I see the option to prevent Wallpaper changes, but I don’t see anyway to change the wallpaper programmatically.

Comment: SO is a question and answer site. Note that *question* is singular, not plural. If you have multiple questions, they need to be in separate posts. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account here.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to change the wallpaper in kiosk mode. However, there is an existing feature request to enable this functionality via **kioskCustomLauncherEnabled**. The request is currently in Engineering's backlog. Unfortunately, there is no guarantee that Engineering will pick up the request for future work. As such, we have no sharable timelines or additional info.

I suggest that you [Join the Android Management API mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-management-api/join) to receive monthly updates and service advisories directly to your inbox.

Comment: Can we build a customer launcher for this ?